# In JavaScript how can I get the data stored in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I wrote this in my JavaScript part to get the data in json file

```js
$.getJSON("BusStop.json", function(data){
               $.each(data, function(i,item){
                 alert("It can be read");
               });
           });
```

And here is the BusStop.json

```js
 [
   { "id":"s01", "name":" ", "longitude":11.603930, "latitide":52.132986},
   { "id":"s02", "name":" ", "longitude":11.609036, "latitide":52.130254},
   { "id":"s03", "name":" ", "longitude":11.608465, "latitide":52.136035},
   { "id":"s04", "name":" ", "longitude":11.580057, "latitide":52.138208},
   { "id":"s05", "name":" ", "longitude":11.590206, "latitide":52.134975},
   { "id":"s06", "name":" ", "longitude":11.584155, "latitide":52.131956},
   { "id":"s07", "name":" ", "longitude":11.591673, "latitide":52.128685},
   { "id":"s08", "name":" ", "longitude":11.620244, "latitide":52.136367},
   { "id":"s09", "name":" ", "longitude":11.612250, "latitide":52.126829},
   { "id":"s10", "name":" ", "longitude":11.597864, "latitide":52.126576}
    
      
]
```

But nothing happened, and I have changed the json file to BusStop.js, nothing happened. Is there anybody who knows the reason? I want to store the longitude and latitude in an array, such as points[].

Comment: Either write out JS in your JSP, or get the data via Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for giving me such a suggestion, which helped me learn a lot, and now I have solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is finally easily solved, just download a file named "jquery-3.2.1.min"
and add this source to html.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```